# Override node packages on react-native

Tags: react-native

I have a set of alias defined on `package.json` is there a way to cascade this configuration through the dependencies?

I have this on my `package.json`

```
"react-native": 
  "net": "react-native-tcp"
}
```

but every dependency that requires `net` throws an error.

**EDIT:**

I was using the `net` package directly and it worked fine because the package was being replaced by `react-native-tcp`.

Now I was trying to use `is-port-reachable` that has the `net` as a dependency but since this package doesn't have the `react-native` information on `package.json` I get an error that my application cannot require `net`

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "is-port-reachable": "1.0.0",
    "react": "15.3.0-rc.2",
    "react-native": "0.31.0-rc.1",
    "react-native-tcp": "2.0.1"
  },
  "react-native": {
    "net": "react-native-tcp"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what/why you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: My question was updated.

Comment: Could you share your whole package.json